# Why can "low" become "lower" and "lowest", while "up" can't?

Tags: adjectives, superlatives

Why can "**low**" become **lower** (comparative) and **lowest** (superlative), while "**up**" can become only comparative (**upper**), rather than superlative (**uppest**)?

The second question is what does act as a **substitute** for superlative of "**up**"? I believe that it's needed in the language.

---

Editing: 
After reading some answers here who claim that the word "**up**" is not an adjective and "upper" is not the opposite of "**lower**". I had to support my initial premise by [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up) that shows that there is an **adjective** which is called "**up**". In addition [in the same dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upper) the word "**upper**" is marked as **adjective** and the word "**lower**" is marked there as a **opposite**. unlike the most of the answers here.

In addition, what's about "**more up**" is the following context "If you feel a bit depressed today, maybe your mood will tomorrow be **more up**." Is this not considered as a comparative adjective of "**up**"?

Comment: Rather than uppest, uppermost is used. Similarly, lowermost can be used as an alternative for lowest. It is possible, though I cannot say, that lowest is a contraction.

Answer (score 214):

Well, the opposite of **low** isn't **up** but **high**, which has the comparative **higher** and the superlative **highest**. So they're equivalent in that regard.

The opposite of **up** would be **down**. But **up** and **down** when used to describe relative directions are adverbs, not adjectives, and they don't have direct comparative and superlative forms (unlike say, *badly*, *worse*, and *worst*). While I don't see anything technically wrong with saying *more/most up/down*, that's not something you really hear in practice. Instead we can say something is *farther up/down* or *farthest up/down*.

**Upper** is a plain adjective, not a comparative. You can say: *John is in **upper** management*, but you wouldn't say *John is **upper** than Jim*. Also, while **downer** is a word, it's a slang noun and not an adjective. **downest** is generally not recognized as a word as far as I know, but neither is **uppest**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer 1^. Regarding to **"up"** and **"low"**, I don't really understand your things since as we know from the **"upper"** part and **"lower"** part (e.g. in anatomy) they seems to be opposite. Isn't it? Second, is it OK to say "**more /most up**" or "**more /most down**"? Or just farther and farthest are OK for them as comparative and superlative adjectives?

Comment: It's confusing, but when used in phrases like *upper jaw* and *lower jaw*, *upper* and *lower* aren't comparatives but are plain adjectives that describe a trait of an object without regards to comparison to another, like *big* or *small*. So *upper* and *lower* are opposites, but only in that regard. *up* and *low* aren't since *up* is a noun and *low* is an adjective. It's best to think of *upper* and *lower* as distinct words from *up* and *low* rather than a special form of those words. (Although, yes, the comparative form of *low* happens to be *lower*).

Comment: You can't really say *more/most up/down* because *up* and *down* are nouns not adjectives (in the sense we're using them here; *up* and *down* both have related adjectival definitions, which have similar but distinct meanings from how we're using them).

Comment: @dbb with you can use more/most up/down within the context of feelings.  E.g How are you feeling?  This is the most down I've been since my dog died.

Comment: +1, though the *up* and *down* in *farther/farthest up/down* are actually not nouns, but rather intransitive prepositions. (And in traditional grammars that don't accept the notion of intransitive prepositions, they're considered adverbs.)

Comment: @ruakh "Intransitive preposition" is a notion so characterised and named in Huddleston & Pullum's Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. We don't have to adopt that grammar's model of the language or its terminology.

Comment: @Rosie: Firstly, the concept is much older than you think; but secondly, in the very comment you're replying to, I also indicated how other grammars handle them. So your fears are unwarranted.

Comment: Honestly, this answer is a real downer. Or maybe an upper.

Comment: Based on Cambridge dictionary the word "up" can be: an **adverb, a preposition, and an adjective!**. So I don't know why you refereed only to one definition of the word while it has 3 different functions. And yes, there is also "up" as adjective. This "up" is indeed doesn't behave as its friends short adjectives who get -er and -est in the comparative and superlative grades, and it is exception that may have many explanations (for example:  avoiding missing up between the different function of the word due to its high usage)  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up?q=UP

Comment: @subtle_sibling The upside of using up as an adjective is self evident :P

Comment: "Upper" is also an accepted term for a stimulant, such as caffeine, a cigarette, or cocaine. Depressants are also called "downers" .

Comment: And the reason that up and down as adverbs cannot be made comparative or superlative is because they are directions and generally something can't be more in a certain direction than it already is. (norther? lefter?) However when you are talking about distance along a direction then you can say things like 'farther up' or 'the farthest east'.

Comment: @subtle_sibling Two of the three meanings of _up_ as an adjective do not match what you are asking about here: they are absolutes, not gradable. An escalator is either an up escalator or a down escalator, and a computer system is either up or down—what would a ‘more up’ escalator or a ‘more up system’ even be? The third one (‘feeling happy’) can be used comparatively or superlatively, but it’s quite rare; see Kevin’s comment above.

Comment: Please, read the editing in the original post. According to Cambridge the opposite of "upper" is "lower".

Comment: @subtle_sibling Please re-read this answer. **That is a different word**. _Upper_ and _lower_ are indeed opposites, but while _lower_ is the comparative form of _low_, _upper_ is not the comparative of _up_. _Up_ does not have a morphological comparative (in the ‘feeling happy’ sense, you’d use _more up_); _upper_ is the **base** (positive) form of a separate adjective. Cambridge seems to count _lower_ as a separate adjective as well, which makes for a neater system, but is not really necessary. So the answer to your question is _more up_ and _most up_, but both are very rare.

Comment: Outside those three, rather uncommon adjectival senses (of which only one logically permits a comparative or superlative), there is no need for a comparative or superlative of _up_ because _up_ is not an adjective. It is a preposition (in some contexts traditionally an adverb, but also analysable as a preposition there), and prepositions do not generally have comparatives or superlatives. Adjectivally, as this answer states, you would normally use _high_, not _up_.

Comment: This should be disqualified from being the highest voted answer because it does not mention **upmost**, which is the missing link in the OP.

Answer (score 35):

The word you're looking for is **uppermost** or **upmost**:

> *adjective*
>   Highest in place, rank, or importance.
>
> *adverb*
>   At or to the highest or most important position.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uppermost)</sub>

There are a number of words like this that end in "-most" such as: uttermost/utmost (from "utter", which itself is from "out"), innermost, outermost, and lowermost (which is synonymous with "lowest").

Etymologically, the suffix "-most" is related to the suffix "-est". If you're curious, here's the etymology of "-most" given by the Oxford English Dictionary:

> Cognate with Gothic *-umist-* , a superlative suffix found in six adjectives (e.g. *auhumists* highest, cognate with Old English *ȳmest* ) < the Germanic base of the superlative suffix in *-m-* attested in Old English *forma* first, *hindema* last ( < the same Indo-European base as the suffix attested in classical Latin *prīmus* prime adj.) + the Germanic base of -est suffix

Comment: Uppermost is superlative but there is no comparative.

Comment: Also note that the opposite of *uppermost* or *upmost* is *lowermost* or *downmost*; even here, we don't make an antonym of *upmost* by replacing "up" by "low".

Comment: So how can I make a comparative sentence regarding to the word "up"? Should I say it's more up or what?

Answer (score 15):

As was pointed out, "up" and "low" are not direct antonyms.

The antonymn of "up" is "down". Neither of these have a comparative or superlative form.
*Note that "downer" and "upper" are existing words, but are not listed as a comparative form.*

The antonym of "low" is "high". Both of these have a comparative (lower/higher) and superlative (lowest/highest).

---

There is one case I can think of where "up" and "low" are opposites of each other: **uppercase** (ABCDE..., also known as *capital* letters) and **lowercase** (abcde...).

> [**Fun fact!**](https://wonderopolis.org/wonder/why-are-there-uppercase-and-lowercase-letters)
>
> Individual pieces of metal type [which is a "letter stamp" used by printing presses] were kept in boxes called cases. The smaller letters, which were used most often, were kept in a lower case [e.g. the bottom shelf] that was easier to reach. Capital letters, which were used less frequently, were kept in an upper case [e.g. the top shelf]. Because of this old storage convention, we still refer to small letters as **lowercase** and capital letters as **uppercase**.

Notice that "upper" is used here. While it's not grammatically the comparative of "up", "upper" by itself is still a valid word that fits in this situation:

> [**Upper**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upper)
>
> 1. Situated above another part.
>      1.1. Higher in position or status.
> 2. Situated on higher ground.

Comment: I was going to post that your fun fact was a false etymology, because most of these stories of word histories on the internet that sound too pat to be true really are just totally made up, but to my shock, the O.E.D. agrees with you. I'm definitely glad to have been wrong about this one. What a nifty and unexpected fun fact! :) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @BenI.: I'm similarly cynical; I spent some time checking this before I wanted to add it to my answer ;)

Comment: Prior to these physical cases of letter stamps, you still had a notion of capital and smaller letters, right? What were they referred to as? Capital letters and... small letters? Normal letters?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I'm pretty sure the technical term for them is _minuscule_ (lower) and _majuscule_ (upper). French still uses these names today.

Comment: Please, read the editing in the original post. According to Cambridge dictionary the opposite of "upper" is "lower".

Comment: @subtle_sibling But "upper" is not the comparative form of "up". Upper's antonym has nothing to do with up's antonym, since one is not just a comparative form of the other.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but it seems that you meant to say that the opposite of  "upper" isn't "lower" and Cambridge the opposite exact.

Comment: @subtle_sibling The question, as it is (and was) phrased, is focusing on "up" and "low" and their comparative/superlative forms. "Upper", while it looks like a comparative, is not actually a comparative, and thus strictly speaking irrelevant to the question that is asked.

Comment: As the OP, let me tell you that I didn't focus on 'up' or 'low'. For me, in the initial premise, there wasn't a difference between the two exept for the grades (degrees) of the comparison, thus I couldn't focus on something in the original post.

Answer (score 10):

@dbb and @laurel have explained things perfectly, I only wish to complement and expand on their excellent answers.

*Upper* belongs to a category of English comparatives that are either losing or have lost their comparative meaning and are mainly used as positive. Excluding *old* and *elder*, the next six examples also have more than one superlative.

> *[upper](https://www.etymonline.com/word/upper) (adj.)*
>   c. 1300, **originally comparative of *up*** (adj.). Similar formation in Middle Dutch *upper*, Dutch *opper*, Low German *upper*, Norwegian *yppar*e.
>
> Source: *Etymonline*

### inner, outer, utter, and upper

```
POSITIVE.      COMPARATIVE.      SUPERLATIVE.

old             older              oldest
 –              elder              eldest

 _              former           foremost, first

in (adverb)     inner            inmost, innermost

out (adverb)    outer            outmost, outermost

 –              utter            utmost, uttermost

up (adverb)     upper            upmost, uppermost 

low             lower            lowest, lowermost
```

Digging deeper, I found the following [excerpt](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QosPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22that%20they%20cannot,%20like%20other%20comparatives,%20be%20construed%20with%20the%20conjunction%22&source=bl&ots=KLVBuk4yAH&sig=86rIVgyocQTZOVZq92JrC5TXUpg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd5-7ej_jaAhUhnuAKHZNgAqUQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22that%20they%20cannot%2C%20like%20other%20comparatives%2C%20be%20construed%20with%20the%20conjunction%22&f=false), edition 1865, which observes that *upper* is used differently from most comparative adjectives. Note that neither *lower* nor *higher* are included in this list.

> Obs 4 – It may be remarked of the comparatives *former* and *latter* or *hinder*, ***upper*** and *under* or *nether*, *inner* and *outer* or *utter* *after* and *hither*; as well as of the Latin *superior* and *inferior*, *anterior* and *posterior*, *interior* and *exterior*, *prior* and *ulterior*, *senior* and *junior*, *major* and *minor*; that they cannot, like other comparatives, be construed with the conjunction *than*, introducing the latter term of comparison; for we never say “one thing is *former*, *superior*, etc., THAN an other”

### *Higher* is not always the opposite of *lower*.

We can talk about the **lower site** and the **upper site** of an institution. In the UK, **lower school** will cater to children between the ages of 4 and 9, **middle school** from 9 to 11, while the **Upper school** will educate students between the ages of 11 and 18. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_education#United_Kingdom))

In medicine, we talk about the **upper limb**; the arm, forearm and hand, and the **lower limb**; thigh, leg and foot. In anatomy, "upper" refers to the POSITION *above* another part (i.e., superior), “*my upper lip is sore*”, while *lower* refers to the position *below* another part (i.e.inferior) “*his lower lip was swollen*”. If humans possessed four lips, we could say (I'm not saying we do) the lip positioned above all the others **[uppermost](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uppermost)**, whilst the bottom lip would be the **[lowermost](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lowermost)** (*lowest*).

### Up and Down

You *turn up* the volume to hear better. (*turn up* =increase)
You *turn down* the sound when the neighbours complain. (*turn down* =decrease)

You climb ***up*** a mountain in the morning
You climb ***down*** before it gets dark

You go **up** to town if you live outside the city
You go **down** to town (or *downtown*) if you live nearby. (But there's some debate over its semantics)

In none of these instances is "up" or "down" an adjective. If I climb *up* something, it tells you in *which* direction I am climbing.

*[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/low-or-short)* tells us

> We use *low* for things which are not high, or which are close to the ground or to the bottom of something:
>
> 1. We have a sofa, two armchairs and a **low** table.
> 2. The wall is too **low**; we need to make it *higher* so the dog can’t get out.

### Comparing *low* and *high*

Two mountain climbers are resting, they are at two different points. Mountaineer A is positioned at 2,000m while mountaineer B is at 2,500m.

> - A is ***lower*** down.
> - B is ***higher*** up.

Alternatively

> - B is ***further*** **up** the mountain (i.e heading up or upwards)
>     *[She walked further up the hill.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/further_1)*

But if the two were descending:

> - A would be ***further*** **down** the mountain. (i.e heading down or downwards)

However, I should point out that the latter is more commonly used for horizontal distances, e.g.

> further down the path
>   further down the stream
>   further down the line

Comment: Please, see my editing. Second, it's not only in medicine. See here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upper "upper floor" (and it makes sense for "lower floors" as well)

Comment: @subtle_sibling I think you need to read the first paragraph more carefully, I never said that upper is used only in medicine. In fact, I gave two other examples, "upper site" and "upper school"

Comment: "If humans possessed three lips, we could say the lip positioned above the other two as uppermost, whilst the bottom lip would be the lowermost." Noooo... the abdomen is composed of three regions, the upper abdomen, the middle or mid-abdominal region, and the lower abdomen. I can't think of a thing in medicine which is "lowermost". Lowest, or deepest, yes. But I live in the US; maybe the Brits say lowermost.

Comment: "If humans possessed three lips, we *could* say the lip positioned above the other two as uppermost" It's an option, and I mentioned it to illustrate the meaning of *uppermost*. If humans had three lips we would most probably say: bottom (lip), middle (lip), and top (lip). The dictionary definition of ***uppermost*** is [***At*** *or nearest* ***the top*** *of something*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uppermost)

Answer (score 1):

### These are different types of words entirely

To put the already re-iterated answer a different way: this is a bit like asking

> Why can this tiger roar when that cucumber consists mostly of water?

The objects `tiger` and `cucumber` are only remotely related, in this case by virtue of both (at least *having been*) alive, and in your question by virtue of both having to do with three-dimensional space.

### The difference

`Up` defines a direction in three-dimensional space, is (in the context of your question) an adverb (and sometimes a noun), and is not comparable (nouns are, of course, never comparable). Hence the words `upper` and `uppermost` are not inflections of the adverb `up`; in fact, the **adjective** `upper` is the **positive** inflection of the comparative `uppermore` and superlative `uppermost`. Incidentally, `upper` is also sometimes used as a noun.

`Low` defines a (usually relative) position in three-dimensional space, is an adjective, and is comparable. Hence it has the comparative inflection `lower` and superlative inflection `lowest`.

#### Examples showing the usage of upper (and its inflections), as requested

I will use similar sentences to illustrate the usage of all three inflections.

**Upper**: I think I will take an `upper` bunk tonight.

In this sentence, I am saying that I intend to **not use the bottom** bunk. In the case of having only two bunks stacked on top of each other, `upper` and `uppermost` are analogous. However, if there were three bunks stacked on top of each other, `an upper bunk` would simply designate one of the bunks that is **not the bottom bunk**, ie. either the second from the top or the top bunk.

---

**Uppermore**: Carl will sleep in an `uppermore` bunk tonight.

Imagine a room with bunks stacked four high, and that last night, Carl slept in the second bunk from the bottom. This sentences states that Carl will, tonight, sleep in a bunk that is further from the ground (than his previous one), but not necessarily the...

---

**Uppermost**:  You should take the `uppermost` bunk tonight.

Imagine a room with bunks stacked as high as you would like. No matter how many bunks are stacked on top of each other, `the uppermost bunk` will always refer to the top (or `topmost`, which is a viable, and maybe even more common, alternative to `uppermost`) bunk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So can we say that the adjective "upper" is the positive (or the base form) while the comparative is uppermore and the superlative is the uppermost? I'd like to see examples for those three.

Comment: Yes, you have hit the nail square on the head, upper is indeed the base form of the adjective. However, as will be explained in my edited answer, its usage sometimes suggests otherwise.

Comment: @subtle_sibling check my updated answer for examples.

Comment: There are no results for "uppermore" in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&query=uppermore), in [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=uppermore),  [Cambridge Dic.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=uppermore) or [Macmillan Dic.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=uppermore)

Comment: Please support the claim that the sentence "…take the uppermore bunk…" is ever used, in speech or writing.

Comment: I found an evidence for that, that it is ever used, but this evidence is a long time ago: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ZYL6DU4rU4oC&pg=PA994&dq=uppermore+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN7c72s97aAhXHZ1AKHaikDpwQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=uppermore%20dictionary&f=false In addition I found it in a medical dictionary: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=UKdTDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT3264&dq=uppermore+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN7c72s97aAhXHZ1AKHaikDpwQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=uppermore%20dictionary&f=false

Comment: in the middle English dictionary: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vvQTsNoDGLQC&pg=PA654&dq=uppermore+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd0ZnetN7aAhVQKVAKHXk8Di44FBDoAQhYMAk#v=onepage&q=uppermore%20dictionary&f=false and others - see here: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=uppermore+dictionary&tbm=bks&ei=gCrlWt2RG9DSwAL5-LjwAg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=613&dpr=1 Anyway there are a very few results for this word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Alhough OP beat me to it, I will say that one would struggle to find an _existing_ example, possibly because of its very limited usefulness and readily available alternative words. However, I would submit to you that there is _no_ adjective in the English language that has a superlative, but no comparative form; they are either comparable or non-comparable. Thus, I must conclude that `uppermore` **must** exist in order to conform to the conventions of the language, but it is certainly of exceptional rarity. However, If you could find such an adjective, I would reconsider.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I also suggest that certain words are simply so rare that they are, whether for brevity, by negligence or by ignorance, left out of even these excellent dictionaries. An example would be `philodox` - which _may well_ be an accurate description of _me_ in this context ;) - which is found only in **1** out of the 4 you mentioned. It is certainly a lot more common than `uppermore`, so it is not unimaginable that extremely rare words may be omitted from all 4. As a personal note, I tend towards the opinion that dictionaries follow the language, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out opposite of low is not up, its high, and high can be "higher" and "highest"

The better question is: Why are up, and down so different.  You have an "upper" level ..not a "downer" level, and you go up to the top and down to the bottom.. but downer has a whole new meaning not related really to physical height, direction or value, that up and down are associated with.

Answer (score 0):

**Up** and **Down** are directions, whereas **High** and **Low** are vectors.

You can tell someone to go in a particular direction for a certain distance, but the direction itself doesn't imply how far one should go. So you could say something like *"Turn left and walk for 200 meters"*, but here *"Turn left"* doesn't say anything about how far you should go, just the direction in which to travel.

**High** and **Low**, on the other hand, have both direction and (relative) magnitude.  So something like *"the bird flew higher than a 747"* tells you the *position* of the bird in relation to a 747.

There's no need for a word like '**uppest**' because the word '**up**' doesn't even tell you the position of an object at all, so how can something be '**upper**'?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to admit that although I read your answer again and again, I didn't understand it at all. Of course, I know what direction and vectors are, but couldn't do the relation between the terms up, down, high and low. In addition, Can you support your claim that "Up and Down are directions, whereas High and Low are vectors" by a reference?