# Are there non-gradable adjectives for comparison?

Tags: adjectives

In the last week I asked here on ELL two questions:

1. [How can these two types of adjectives be distinguished terminologically?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/164654/12430)
2. [Why can “low” become “lower” and “lowest”, while “up” can't?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/164494/12430)

The answer for the first question is "**inflectionally gradable** for comparison and **analytically gradable** for comparison".

The answer for the second question as I understood by reading all the answers there, is that the word "**up**" is not an adjective and therefore it should **not** be **gradable**. But when I see [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up) we can see that there is an adjective which is called "up". In addition [in the same dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upper) the word "upper" is marked as adjective. (and the word "lower" is marked there as a opposite. unlike the most of the answers in the second post). So it confuses me because I'm not sure if the word "**up**" is gradable or no.

Then my question is: *Are there **adjectives** that are non gradable at all?*

Answer (score 1):

Sure. For example *wooden* in *wooden spoon.*

You can't (at least ordinarily) have a *woodener* or *woodenest* spoon.

We can say *He divorced her* but not *He's divorceder.*

Comment: He the **most divorced** person I have ever met.

Comment: *The same study did find, however, that the annual incomes of divorced women were greater than the incomes of women who were still married, a finding at least partly attributable to the fact that* [***more divorced*** *than married women are employed full time.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-YwsDr3fW1cC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22more+divorced+than%22&source=bl&ots=pQkIyOr3cP&sig=1XSglVM1Tvg9B4TCfILUw1qpuNg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8rfbkkt_aAhVwzlkKHQygCHQQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q=%22more%20divorced%20than%22&f=false)

Comment: The adjective *divorced* has two syllables and it doesn't end in "y", therefore it would not take the -er suffix of monosyllables such as "tall" or disyllables such as "happy".

Comment: ① In *He divorced her*, the word *divorced* is a verb and not an adjective. ② In *more divorced than married women are employed full time*, the adjective *divorced* is not gradable.  Rather, the number of divorced women is being compared to the number of married women.  Try a *very* test instead: *\*very divorced* is unacceptable unless you can come up with a context permitting a novel interpretation of *divorced* with a semantic dimension along which the meaning can be graded; *He is the most divorced person I have ever met* would presumably require such a context.

Comment: @snailboat My comment was to show how the to make the comparative and the superlative adjective "divorced": more divorced--->most divorced. The offered version *divorceder* is ungrammatical (you're right to point out that divorced in "he divorced" is a verb). One is either divorced or not, one is either pregnant or not, but native speakers do say "very pregnant". So I wouldn't be surprised if someone who had been divorced more than five times was described as being "very divorced". If nothing else, "more/most divorced" is grammatical (perhaps not idiomatic, but that's a separate issue).

Comment: @snailboat I didn't receive a notification when you posted your comment, I was just browsing by.

Comment: Those are some of the adjectiviest comments I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is basically asking about *comparative* and *superlative* adjectives.
While

> **low, lower, lowest**

exists

> **down, downer, downest**

does not.
In the same way

> **high, higher, highest**

exists, but

> **up, upper, uppest**

does not.

Perhaps this might help you: [Comparative and Superlative Adjectives](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives/)

Comment: Actually, "upper" does exist. Upper crust, upper class, upper income, etc.

Comment: I was using the *three-tuple*, **uppest** does not exist.